# Why does one Swing keystroke work but not the other?

Tags: java, swing, keystroke

I am writing a Swing program that has a JTable; I want to use control-V to paste into the JTable, and control-S to save the information that's on the JTable.

I first used `JTable.registerKeyboardAction()` to register the action with the control-V key, and that works, but I noticed that its javadoc says it is obsolete and that new code should use the input map and action map for this purpose.

I had used those for the control-S key, which I had also mapped to a JButton, so I figured it would be easy to duplicate. Here's the code snippet I have now for creating the JFrame:

```
  private JFrame createMainframe()
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("VisaExtraction");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    String saveFileActionName = "Save";
    String pasteActionName = "Paste";

    Action saveFileAction = new SaveFileAction(saveFileActionName, frame, tableModel);
    Action pasteAction    = new PasteAction(pasteActionName, frame, tableModel);

//    JButton saveButton = new JButton(saveFileAction);
//    saveButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);

    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
//    topPanel.add(saveButton);

    mainTable = new LastColumnChangesWidthJTable(tableModel);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainTable);

    // set ctrl-s to the 'saveFile' action
    //  and ctrl-v to the 'paste' action
    InputMap  tableInputMap  = mainTable.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

    KeyStroke saveKeystroke  = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
    tableInputMap.put(saveKeystroke, saveFileActionName);

    KeyStroke pasteKeystroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
    tableInputMap.put(pasteKeystroke, pasteActionName);

    // set the saveFile and paste actions to be executed when invoked.
    ActionMap tableActionMap = mainTable.getActionMap();
    tableActionMap.put(saveFileActionName,  saveFileAction);
    tableActionMap.put(pasteActionName,     pasteAction);

    frame.add(topPanel,   BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.pack();

    // register ctrl-v to paste into the JTable
//    mainTable.registerKeyboardAction
//    ( actionListener -> handlePaste(tableModel, new VisaExtractionListener(tableModel)),
//      KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), 
//      JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW
//    );

    return frame;
  }
```

As you can see, I'm doing the same things with "S" and "save" that I'm doing with "V" and "paste", but after I start the program, "control-S" works (to the extent of telling me there's nothing to save) and "control-V" does not (the breakpoint in the `actionPerformed()` method is not hit).

What could be causing the difference between these two?

Comment: Best to create and post a valid [mcve]. You're an experienced Stack Overflow user, and so I'm a bit surprised that you haven't done this yet.

Comment: `As to MVCEs, I agree they're useful, but don't think they're always necessary.` - You just stated you wrote some code and it doesn't work the way you expect. So the whole point is to then post the code so we can see exactly what you did. Not only can we make sure you didn't make a silly mistake, we can use that as a basis for our own testing. Until a problem is solved you don't know what information is needed to solve a problem. Better to post all the information up front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely due to the JTable already using ctrl-V action in another input map. Understand that components have 3 input maps, and I believe that the one for `JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED` has precedence over `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`.

My MCVE for proof of concept. Change the commented field in the code below to see which works:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[][] rowData = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
        String[] columnNames = {"A", "B"};
        JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        // int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
        int condition = JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED;
        InputMap inputMap = table.getInputMap(condition);
        ActionMap actionMap = table.getActionMap();

        KeyStroke saveKeystroke  = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        KeyStroke pasteKeystroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);

        inputMap.put(saveKeystroke, saveKeystroke.toString());
        inputMap.put(pasteKeystroke, pasteKeystroke.toString());

        actionMap.put(saveKeystroke.toString(), new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("save action");
            }
        });
        actionMap.put(pasteKeystroke.toString(), new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("paste action");
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Again in the future, the effort of creating the MCVE should be yours since you are the one asking for help.

Edit: I was wrong. The input map that was already in use and was messing you up was the `JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` map. This had a non-null key String for the control-V key in my MCVE update:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createGui());
    }

    public static void createGui() {
        Integer[][] rowData = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
        String[] columnNames = { "A", "B" };
        JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        int condition = JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT;
        // int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
        // int condition = JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED;
        InputMap inputMap = table.getInputMap(condition);
        ActionMap actionMap = table.getActionMap();

        KeyStroke saveKeystroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        KeyStroke pasteKeystroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);

        String pasteKey = (String) inputMap.get(pasteKeystroke);
        System.out.println(pasteKey);

        inputMap.put(saveKeystroke, saveKeystroke.toString());
        inputMap.put(pasteKeystroke, pasteKeystroke.toString());

        actionMap.put(saveKeystroke.toString(), new MyAction("Save Action"));
        actionMap.put(pasteKeystroke.toString(), new MyAction("Paste Action"));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
    private String text;

    public MyAction(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: That does solve the problem, thanks. The order of searching IS in the Oracle tutorial "How to Use Key Bindings", but the search order is not something I've paid enough attention to in the past.

Comment: As to MVCEs, I agree they're useful, but don't think they're always necessary. Someone (like you) who understands how the facilities in question work, can often spot a problem or a potential problem and set the questioner right without much trouble. You didn't have to give working code to answer the question at all; if you had just said "Swing searches through different maps to match a keystroke, maybe there's another taking precedence", that would have given me enough to go on. In any event, thanks again.

Comment: @arcy: I didn't say necessary but they're damn convenient. Again in order for me to figure this out, I had to first create an MCVE and test the code and then alter it. But why should I have to do this effort when the responsibility for making the question easy to answer is yours? This is more of an issue of onus of responsibility.